# How can I use multiple timers in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, vbscript, timer

I'm working on a Quiz game, and I want to calculate time taken for each question. I'm thinking of a basic solution, which would be to start timer2 when the question is generated for the user, then stop timer2 when the user selects an answer, then finally show the time elapsed for timer2 in a label.

However today I realized that you cannot use more than two timers in Visual Studio, because in Visual Studio only one timer can run at once simultaneously.

By the way, In my quiz game timer1 is used as a countdown timer.

**So, my question is how can I run two timers at once on Visual Studio 2013?**

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can have many active timers, and the number of timers you can have is not restricted by Visual Studio or any other IDE. However you probably want a [stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the second timer.

Comment: Note that for your objective, you don't really need timers. Simply, store the question start time (DateTime questionstart=DateTime.Now). When you get the response, deduce duration (TimeSpan duration=DateTime.Now-questionstart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timer is the wrong tool for the job. Perhaps for the overall countdown timer it is OK as you are essentially saying "trigger x event after y period of time". But for measuring how long something took, you should instead use `Stopwatch`.

```
// at start of the question
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

// when they select an answer
stopwatch.Stop();

// example of getting time taken
stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

PS: Stopwatch is not limited to one at a time.

Comment: Hey man, I'll try that right now, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: PS. I added a photo of what I'm exactly trying to do for clarity.

Comment: When I add the code exactly as you said, I get a error-   " 'Stopwatch' is a type and cannot be used as a expression."

Comment: I'm using vb.net by the way, not C#.

Comment: Dim stopwatch As New Stopwatch() ... Dim responseTimeInSeconds As Integer = (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + 500) / 1000 ;

Comment: Then you shouldn't have put C# in the question tags

Comment: Yep, sorry, Was a mistake on my part. I'm trying the solutions above, right now.

Comment: Alright, I implemented everything, but now the number is in a format like this, "4578". I need it to be Seconds:Miliseconds if possible... And what is the need for "+ 500) / 1000" ?

Comment: If you apply "(n+ 500) / 1000" to 4200 ms, you fill get 4 seconds. For 4800 ms, it will give you 5 seconds. This formula may be replaced by "Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToDouble(n)/1000))".

Comment: @Graffito - The `Elapsed` property of the `Stopwatch` class is an instance of `TimeSpan`.  You can use the `ToString` method to format the output:  `Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("ss\:ff"))`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : Good remark! int delayInSeconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.

Comment: How would I implement... Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("ss\:ff")) ?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : Are you saying do this: 

`Public responseTimeInSeconds As Integer = Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("ss\:ff"))`

In declarations?

Comment: @CrazyRussianHacker - If you just want to put the time in a label, you can do this instead:  `label1.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("ss\:ff")`